# having a time with 2 digits when using DATEPART

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below

```
DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE()) AS HOURS
```

while the first hours results is :  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...etc, am looking to get a result of

00,01,02,03,04,05,...10,11,12,...,22,23

Comment: The value "01" is a string value, and the output of `DATEPART()` is an integer.  Maybe use `FORMAT()` ?  see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This is honestly something for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: @Luuk appreciated your advice. thx